# luaL_dofile Error

Tags: c++, lua

Error at line "luaL_dofile" and debugger doesn't show anything about error.

I can use command "luaL_dostring" but I don't know why I can't dofile.

My code is following:

```
const char* file = "/app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua";
ret = luaL_dofile(LS, file);
if(ret != 0){
    PRINTF("Error occurs when calling luaL_dofile() Hint Machine 0x%x\n",ret);
    }
else PRINT("\nDOFILE SUCCESS");
```

and debugger shows error in this line and "ret" still not get returned value from dofile.

If you want to see about error in debugger

**02C2D304 7C21016A stdux      r1,r1,r0                      03 (02C2D300) REG PIPE LSU**

Debugger points in this line and I can't understand it.

Comment: You should provide more information if you want to get an answer - what is the error, show some code around the line it happens on, etc.

Comment: Debugger shows error in this line and I found assembly code that I can't understand.

This is my code:

ret = luaL_dofile(LS, file);
 if(ret != 0){
  PRINTF("Error occurs when calling luaL_dofile() 0x%x\n",ret);
     }
 else PRINT("\nDOFILE SUCCESS");

Comment: Please edit your question and place that there. Also make it syntax highlighted for better reading by using the utilities in the editor - the {} button.

Comment: This problem was happened when I formatted my window. I can run code "dofile" before my computer was formatted. That's why I'm not sure about program that I missed to install.

Comment: `luaL_dofile` leaves an error message at the top of the Lua stack. Get it with `lua_tostring(L,-1)` and print it. Also, tell us the value of `ret`.

Comment: RET : (null) after I use 

`PRINTF("RET : %s\n", lua_tostring(LS,-1));`

and RET : 0 if you use %d

Comment: Are you certain that dostring is working correctly in this setup? I've never had dofile break in a confusing and cryptic fashion for me. The debugger output you've given is just showing a single line of assembly which is all but useless for working out what is going on here, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I'll keep trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an elaboration on superzilla's answer (upvote that answer rather than this one),
to get the error message your code needs to look like this:

```
const char* file = "/app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua";
ret = luaL_dofile(LS, file);
if(ret != 0){
  PRINTF("Error occurs when calling luaL_dofile() Hint Machine 0x%x\n",ret);
  PRINTF("Error: %s", lua_tostring(LS,-1));
}
else PRINT("\nDOFILE SUCCESS");
```

Your change (in the comments) changed the `luaL_dofile` to a `luaL_dostring`, which is why you're getting unexpected error message ( as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999606/error-lual-dostring-unexpected-symbol-near) ).

Comment: I can't. If I use: `luaL_doFile` Debugger will show an error and stop operation in this line. And I can't go to `PRINTF` after `luaL_doFile`.

Comment: OK so what is the error that happens when you run it? (segmentation fault? abort? something else?) What operating system are you using? Have you run your application through valgrind? Have you enabled debug symbols in your build to help us find the error?

Comment: Can you produce a minimal full example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Ok, I will explain. First, I start to run my code with VS 2008 and debugger shows that there is error in line `luaL_dofile`. You can see an error details in my question. It's just assembly code that I can't understand it. So, my project will terminate at line `luaL_dofile`. That's why I can't see result from `PRINTF("Error: %s", lua_tostring(LS,-1));`. Sorry if I confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in the body of your if statement will help us narrow down the problem:

```
printf("%s\\n",lua_tostring(LS,-1));
```

It'll tell us what Lua is reporting when it crashes.

Comment: Thanks guy, I try this:

`const char* file = "/app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua";
 luaL_dostring(LS, file);
 PRINTF("RET : %s\n", lua_tostring(LS,-1));`

and this is an error

**RET : [string "/app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua"]:1: unexpected symbol near '/'**

Comment: What does this mean? Do I miss something in char path?

Comment: @barssala, you want `luaL_dofile` not `luaL_dostring`.

Comment: @barssala posting the lua script would be helpful, or at least the first 10 lines or so.