# Error luaL_doString " unexpected symbol near '/' "

Tags: c++, lua

I got some error when my code is about:

```
    const char* file = "/app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua";
        PRINTF("File : %s\n", file);
        luaL_dostring(LS, file);
PRINTF("RET(File) : %s\n", lua_tostring(LS,-1));
```

and output is :

**File : /app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua**

**RET(File) : [string "/app_home/data/minigames/mg_hint_machine_2.lua"]:1: unexpected symbol near '/'**

I'm pretty sure about my path. Additionally I don't know what symbol that unexpected or

I miss something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `luaL_dofile` instead of `luaL_dostring`.

`luaL_dostring` - tries to execute the string as lua code.

`luaL_dofile` - tries to execute the file that the string points to as lua code.

Comment: I can't. `luaL_dofile` get an error and debugger show error in an assembly code that I can't understand

Comment: If you have to use `luaL_dostring` for some reason, then you'll need to read the file into a char buffer and pass that buffer to `luaL_dostring`. However I suggest you create a *new* question with your errors from `luaL_dofile` instead - as that should not be erroring.

Comment: Thanks but I posted that yesterday

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985604/lual-dofile-error)

Comment: I've added an elaborated answer there now. Hopefully you can get the right error message from `luaL_dofile` if you follow it.